# OS Version without build number C#

Tags: c#, operating-system

how can i get the version of OS without the builder number?
I tried with:

```
Environment.OSVersion.Version
```

but this return, for example "6.2.9200.0" in windows 8, and i only need the version number (6.2), without builder (9200). Also i need that the code work in all OS.

If i use:

```
Environment.OSVersion.Major + "." + Environment.OSVersion.Version.Minor
```

This will work fine in all OS?

Examples:
Windows 8 => 6.2
OSX => 10.5.8

Thanks in advance!

**Edit:**
The problem is, i have a java application that creates a file with OS version (uses function "system.getproperty(os.version)") as regular expression (like this "^10\.5\.\d$").

I need compare this file with the actual OS version using a C# app. So i need a C# function that works like that java function "system.getproperty(os.version)". (I can't change the java application).

Comment: If you do `Environment.OSVersion.Major + "." + Environment.OSVersion.Version.Minor` you will definitely not get `10.5.8`

Comment: but in OSX Version 10.5.8  10 is Major and 5.8 is not Minor?

Comment: `Version.Minor` is an `int` property. There is no way to store `5.8` in an `int` property.

Answer (score 4):

`Environment.OSVersion.Version` is an object of type [`System.Version`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.Version.aspx).

This object has the following method overload: [`ToString(int)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bff8h2e1.aspx), the `int` parameter being the number of fields to return.

Therefore, what you want is:

```
Environment.OSVersion.Version.ToString(2)
```

since you need the first two fields.

For MacOS (that is, when `Environment.OSVersion.Platform == PlatformID.MacOSX`) you can use `ToString(3)`. The exact logic you need is up to you there.

Comment: That will not return `10.5.8` on OSX

Comment: @Marcin yes I realized this after writing the answer, I've added a special case for OS X.

Comment: Thanks. I have the OS version like this "^10\\.5\\.\\d$" and i use this: Regex.IsMatch(Environment.OSVersion.Version, "^10\\.5\\.\\d$", RegexOptions.IgnorePatternWhitespace); to compare actual OS version with OS version "^10\\.5\\.\\d$". How can i change this method to get true if the versions are equals using regular expressions? Example: this: "^6\\.\\d$" == 6.2.9200.0 ? return TRUE;

Comment: I don't know what you're trying to do, but what I know is that you certainly don't need any regex for this task, as `Version` is already a fully parsed structure with all the properties you can ask for.

Comment: the files i use already have the OS version as regular expression and i need compare actual OS version with OS version from file, is regular expression why have expressions as "\d" that indicate a number (0-9) and others expressions...

Comment: I see. Well, to extract a 2-part version you could use `\d+\.\d+`, and for a 3-part version it would be `\d+\.\d+\.\d+`. Once extracted, just compare the match with `Environment.OSVersion.Version.ToString(2)` or `ToString(3)`. But perhaps you should add some more context to the regex to avoid false positives (for instance a decimal number could be interpreted as a 2-part version number too). Also, use verbatim strings for regexes: `@"\d+\.\d+"` is easier to read. If you have more issues, you should post a different (regex) question with some examples from your file.

Answer (score 0):

**Update:**

---

The approach you listed will **not** work incongruence with two deviating Operating Systems.  You'll need two different approaches, which will require the `Environment.OSVersion` to correctly initialize and parse the two correctly.

- `Environment.OSVersion.Version`
- `Environment.OSVersion.Platform`

Those will be your two approaches, however if you do the [following](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3a8hyw88%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

```
var os = Environment.OSVersion;
var pid = os.Platform;
```

It will return an `integer` back of six for Mac OS X.

Your other approach:

```
var os = Environment.OSVersion.Version.ToString(2);
```

That would properly solve your issue for determining the *Microsoft Windows Version*, however I'm not sure how it would handle the *Unix / Mac OS X* platform.  Especially with how relatively *new* the Microsoft .Net Core is on non-Microsoft based systems.

Without more detail for why your trying to return specific build number release compared to a friendly name, we won't be much help.  However based on your question and comments.

- Regular Expression:  *You do not need this, not sure why you would use this.*
- Concat `.Major` and `.Minor`: *That will not work either.*

The most common scenario for determining your platform, or the platform your application running:

```
var os = Environment.OSVersion;
var pid = os.Platform;

switch (pid)
{
     case PlatformID.Win32NT:
     case PlatformID.Win32S:
     case PlatformID.Win32Windows:
     case PlatformID.WinCE:
           // Microsoft Windows
           break;

     case PlatformID.Unix:
           // Unix
           break;

     case PlatformID.MacOSX:
           // Macintosh
           break;

     default:
          // Unidentified
          break;
}
```

Could you clarify and add more detail on your goal?

Comment: Thanks, but in OSX, the versions have three parts (i.e: 10.5.8)

Comment: The problem is, i have a java application that creates a file with OS version (uses function "system.getproperty(os.version)"), i need compare this file with the actual OS version using a C# app. So i need a C# function that works like that java function "system.getproperty(os.version)". (I can't change the java application). Thanks